# JFrame - Manual Resizing Issue

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

Good evening,

I created a window with a costum layout and a JPanel. When I resize it manually, it flickers because Java draws the JPanel false to draw it a second time at the right position.

I made a short example-program including my problem:

---

```
public class Starter {

   private static TestWindow testWindow;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     testWindow = new TestWindow();
   }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestWindow {

    private JFrame frame;

    public TestWindow() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 765, 599);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new OwnLayout());

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.add("", pnl);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class OwnLayout implements LayoutManager {

    JPanel pnl;

    public OwnLayout() {
    }

    @Override
    public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        pnl = (JPanel) comp;
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        if (pnl != null)
            pnl.setBounds((int) parent.getWidth() - 50, 0, 50, (int) parent.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
        pnl = null;
    }
 }
```

---

The flickering only appears, when dragging the left border of the frame.
The issue may link to:

> Due to the asynchronous nature of native event handling, the results
>   returned by getBounds, getLocation, getLocationOnScreen, and getSize
>   might not reflect the actual geometry of the Window on screen until
>   the last request has been processed. During the processing of
>   subsequent requests these values might change accordingly while the
>   window management system fulfills the requests.

*(quoted from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html)*

I need a solution to prevent the flickering. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at a few other layout managers, you will generally find that this is the case for all of them and there is no solution to this particular problem

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
There ist really no solution? :/ Maybe something with double buffering?

Comment: When using other layout managers do you encounter the same flickering?

Comment: I think it has to do with the connection between the native peer and the reset of the API, the window isn't updated by the Event Queue, but the Event Queue needs to respond to the changes and which comes back to the way painting is scheduled and optimisied

Comment: @Dank Vader: Yes. The implemented layouts encounter the same problem...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I am not convinced that I understand your point correctly. Because of the reset of the API, the Event Queue does not have the latest informations?
If that is correct, that would be the reason for the two calls of doLayout() for resizing once. That's why I thought double buffering would be a solution.

Comment: Because there is a disconnection between the native/OS message queue and the Event Queue, so OS messages need to be dequeue from the OS message queue and enqueued to the Event Queue there is a delay between what the OS can do (update the window) and the Swing API to repaint it. Add in the fact that the painting process is designed to reduce multiple, quick repaint requests down to a small number of paint requests, you add another delay into the system

Comment: @MadProgrammer:
Okay, thank you for the explanation.
But if there is the delay between the update of the window and the repaint-call, why would the window be drawed with not the latest informations?

Comment: Because the rest of the API doesn't know that the window has changed shape.  Java is not responsible for changing the shape  of the Window the OS is, so the OS can change the shape, which triggers a series of updates through it's native messaging queue which then need to be translated to the Event Queue in Java, in the meantime, the OS has updated the shape of the window

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Ah, thank you. That makes sense.